# How to repair burnt through-hole solder pads on PCB - how to repair?

Tags: pcb, repair, keyboard

I was replacing a switch on my mechanical keyboard and burnt the board while soldering and now the switch and led won't solder in, what should I do? I realized after that I must have bumped the control as it was set to 950F.

This is the board:

[image: image of keyboard]

After cleaning: it's a little better,  I could probably clean some more 
[image: after cleaning]

Comment: First,  you need to get a smaller soldering iron. Second, you need to get some flux remover. Finally, when removing components with multiple pins it's generally best to cut the component into pieces so you can remove each pin smoothly and quickly - so you don't burn the board.

Comment: What a mess! If this is what happens when you try removing components, you shouldn't be trying to remove components from a PCB. You destroyed it to the point that you cannot use the original pads to make connections, which means you can only fix it using a hack (soldering jumpers to different points on the board). You really only need a 15W soldering iron for most PCB work. I'm willing to bet you're using a 40W, which is absurd.

Comment: I realized after that my soldering iron was set to 950F, so that must have been the issue,  it must have been bumped into.

Comment: @Der Strom8: the opposite is true. With a 15W soldering iron, you are bound to put the tip longer -- much too long -- to the board. The more power the iron has, the shorter the heating time. I found a 50W iron is perfect for <1mm diameter tips. One second of heating, move tip away, solder, you are done. De-soldering works same as quick. And no chance to overheat anything. You don't even need fancy temperature control -- it's reacting much too slow anyway.

Comment: @Janka I disagree. In my experience 15W has been more than adequate to solder pins quickly (less than one second for <1mm diameter pins) and are far less likely to burn or lift pads. Higher power irons are also more difficult to tin and you need to tin them far more often, and they burn through tips more quickly than smaller irons. That being said, I'm sure we can all agree that a temperature-controlled iron is far superior to pencil-type, and generally only needs to be set to <650F for most small parts.

Comment: @samocamo123 950F would do it! Yikes!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you've pretty much destroyed the connections. It's still possible to fix it- clean off all that black crud with high purity IPA, carefully scrape off the solder resist with a knife to reveal the copper and solder thin wires from the switch terminals to where the wires should go, and probably you'll have to glue the switch down.

Frankly, based on what I see, you'd be better off to take this to a guy that repairs cell phones and pay them to do it. There are a few of the above tasks that require materials or skills that you'd have to acquire.

Comment: There are people who repair phones at the rework level??

Comment: @ScottSeidman yep, typically same guys that do laptops.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Oh, yes. They can reball BGAs and do all kinds of fantastic things with a small bench and a bit of equipment. This would be ridiculously easy for them. Eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JB1InDsWCjQ

Answer (score 1):

Led is simple enough. Use some small gauge wire and solder it from the led to the two traces on the board that the led solder connections go to. The left hand connection is tied to the led above and below the damaged led connection. The right hand side likely goes somewhere else on the other side of the board.

The switch is trickier because the solder points also provide positioning and support for the switch. It would be difficult to epoxy without breaking the switch.